# how to pass the json data inside javascript regex? and also validate password in sequence

Tags: javascript, html, json, regex

I am trying to validate the password using javascript regex. Now I want to validate two lower case letters (2 small letters) which is coming from json.

```
psw.onkeyup = function() {
  var Lcase = jsonData.LOWERCASE;
  var psw = document.getElementById("password");
  var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]{2}/g;
  if(psw.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {
    letter.classList.remove("invalid");
    letter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    letter.classList.remove("valid");
    letter.classList.add("invalid");
  }
}
```

In the above code I am setting up a variable "Lcase" to json data and now I want to replace "{2}" (inside regex) with that variable "Lcase" coz the "Lcase" variable is dynamic. If I am doing something wrong then please guide me to come out of this problem. 
I want to validate small case letters which is coming from json(dynamic number) to see how many small letters are there in the password string.

For your information the below code for password length is working.

```
  if(psw.value.length >= jsonData.MINLEN_RANGE) {
    length.classList.remove("invalid");
    length.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    length.classList.remove("valid");
    length.classList.add("invalid");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If define your regular expression using RegExp, you can define {2} using Lcase.
This code also includes the question posted on the comments bellow.

```js
psw.onkeyup = function() {
  var Lcase = jsonData.LOWERCASE;
  var psw = document.getElementById("password").value.replace(/([a-z])\d+/g, '$1');
  var lowerCaseLetters = new RegExp('[a-z]{' + Lcase + '}', 'g') 
  if(psw.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {
    letter.classList.remove("invalid");
    letter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    letter.classList.remove("valid");
    letter.classList.add("invalid");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. working as expected
but one more problem is, it is only considering the small letters in sequence 
eg: as123 but not working for eg: a123s

Comment: That is a diffferent issue from the original post, but it also has an easy solution:
  
```js
psw = psw.replace(/([a-z])\d+/g, '$1');
```

Comment: I didn't get you, How I can include this in my code?

Comment: I have modified the code in order to also solve your 2nd problem.
For clarity, you should edit your original post in order to include both problems, otherwise my answer isn't a match to the original post.

Comment: Original post has been modified and your code is working perfectly.. thank you

Comment: The above code is only accepting numbers like "a1a" is working but it is not working for eg: "kAk", K!K", "h^k" and so on.

Comment: sorry, but you have to be more clear and detail regarding this new issue, and also include it on the original post in order for me to provide you assistance.
you should include, the input and expected output.